# How to translate (manually) interface construction from React tsx to React jsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

Here is description how to create modal dialog for the global use in the React application https://dev.to/dmtrkovalenko/the-neatest-way-to-handle-alert-dialogs-in-react-1aoe
Here is codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/neat-dialogs-3h5ou?from-embed=&file=/src/ConfirmationService.tsx

This example uses tsx format.

ConfirmationDialog.tsx contains export of interface:

```
export interface ConfirmationOptions {
  catchOnCancel?: boolean;
  variant: "danger" | "info";
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

And this interface is used in the ConfirmationService.tsx import:

```
const ConfirmationServiceContext = React.createContext<
  (options: ConfirmationOptions) => Promise<void>
>(Promise.reject);
```

AFAIK jsx does not contain `interface` construction and also jsx does not contain construction `React.createContext<...>` (with angle braackets).

My question is - how to translate this interface and this use of interface (in `createContext(...)`) from tsx code to jsx code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two features of Typescript in use in your example: Interface and Generic (the thing inside the <> bracket). Therefore, to convert to JSX, you will:

- not need to import/declare the interface, and
- remove the generic part, like this:

```
const ConfirmationServiceContext = React.createContext(Promise.reject);
```